# How to fix 404 error when installing npm package from GCP artifact registry with yarn?

Tags: npm, google-cloud-platform, yarnpkg, google-artifact-registry

I'm having an issue with installing an NPM package from GCP.

I was able to upload the package to the artifact registry of GCP by doing the following steps:

1. Login to my google account (`gcloud auth application-default login`)
2. Run

   `gcloud artifacts print-settings npm \ --project=[my-project]\ --repository=[my-repo] \ --location=us-east1 \ --scope=@[my-scope]`
3. Pasting the output of the previous step in the `.npmrc` file located in the root of the project.
4. Refreshing the access token to GCP (`npx google-artifactregistry-auth ./.npmrc`)
5. Run `yarn publish`

My `.npmrc` file looks like this:

```
@[my-scope]:registry=https://us-east1-npm.pkg.dev/[my-project]/[my-repo]/
//us-east1-npm.pkg.dev/[my-project]/[my-repo]/:_authToken="[auth-token]"
//us-east1-npm.pkg.dev/[my-project]/[my-repo]/:always-auth=true
```

However, when I try to install the package on another project by:

1. Executing steps 1-4 mentioned above
2. Run `yarn add @[my-scope]/[my-package]`

I get an 404 error.
Looks like yarn is looking for the package in the default registry:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@[my-scope]/@[my-pacakge]/-/@[my-scope]/[my-package]-0.0.1.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".
```

I simply followed the steps mentioned in the installation instructions in GCP but somehow it's not working.

I encountered a similar issue in this post: [Can't install a scoped package I published to a npm registry in GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69353390/cant-install-a-scoped-package-i-published-to-a-npm-registry-in-gcp) but this not the exact error I get.

I would appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had this problem for a couple of days and the solution is simple, **DO NOT USE YARN** when publishing. That's it.

I don't know which part of yarn causes this but basically it ignores .npmrc resulting in the tarball to point to the wrong repository, you can check it if you run `yarn info`. So when publishing to GCP artifact registry one should use `npm publish` instead.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use yarn if you write a `.yarnrc` file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58882143/yarn-with-npmrc-and-authentication

Comment: Yes but in this specific case the auth helper that google wrote only supports npmrc, at least on my tests hence the solution that I recommended.

Comment: Thank you, I struggled a whole day with this issue, and when I switched to using NPM instead of YARN it just worked, I don't know why they didn't add support also for yarn

Answer (score 0):

In both [setting up authentication for npm](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/nodejs/authentication) and [Managing Node.js packages](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/nodejs/manage-packages), **Obtaining an access token** section the command used is

> ```
> npx google-artifactregistry-auth
> ```

In the same section there is a note that explains how to add flags if you need to change the path of the `.npmrc` file.

> **Note:** *If you need to store your repository settings and credentials in .npmrc files other than the defaults, you can run the credential helper with additional flags.*
>
> **--repo-config** is the .npmrc file with your repository settings. If you don't specify this flag, the default location is the current directory.
>
> **--credential-config** is the path to the .npmrc file where you want to write the access token. The default is your user .npmrc file.

Instead of:

> ```
> npx google-artifactregistry-auth ./.npmrc
> ```

It could be written as

```sh
npx google-artifactregistry-auth --repo-config=pathto/.npmrc --credential-config=pathto/.npmrc
```

If you are not sure where your file is you can run  `npm config ls -l | grep config` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17481045/16938011)

Also check you are specifying the correct  `.npmrc` path if it is different than the default registry as shown in [Configuring npm](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/nodejs#npmrc) and confirm you are trying to [install a package from the Node.js package repository](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/nodejs/manage-packages#install) with the correct scope, package, tag or version to be completely explicit.

Comment: I followed again the steps in the links you sent me.
I created a key file for the service account and created an environment variable with the path to it.

 After running `npx google-artifactregistry-auth` without the path as you suggested, the second line in the .npmrc file disappears.
When I do run it with the path to .npmrc, it simply fills the "authToken" value, which is why I assumed that this is the correct way to run this command.

Comment: In addition, what do you mean by ” using an .npmrc per account and not the same configuration file duplicated in each”.
Besides the token, all the other content should be identical in the project where we publish/install the package.

Comment: I've edited my question to try to be more specific. Could you please check it out?